# How to initialize bean method defined in Main class into test context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have created a bean method in the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringApplication{

@Bean
Public String getCronValue(ServiceImpl service){

return service.getConfig().get("cron duration");
}
}
```

using this bean in a scheduled task:

```
@Component
public Class MySch{

@Scheduled(cron="#{getCronValue}")
public void schedulerMethod(){
//Do something
}
}
```

Now the problem is when I try to run JUnit tests @Bean GetCronValue is not initialized in test context and @Scheduled annotation throws an exception:

Update:-

It throws an exception:-
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'SchedulerMethod' : Initialization of bean failed; nested
exception is ' org. springframework.beans.
factory.Beanexpressio exception: Expression parsing
failed; nested exception is org. springframework.
expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1021E: A
problem occurred whilst attempting to access the
property ' getCronValue' : Error creating bean with name
'getCronValue' : Unsetisfied dependency expressed
through method 'getCronValue' parameter 0; nested
exception is org. springframework. beans. factory.
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of
type 'com.pkg.service.ServiceImpl' available: expected at
least 1 bean which qualifies as a autowire candidate.
Dependemcy annotations: {}'

My  Controller test class looks like:-

```
@Transactional
public class ControllerTest{
@MockBean
private Service service;
.
.
// test cases
}
```

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: How do you run your test? Spring Boot testing comes with many options; which ones have you tried?

Comment: Using Mockito framework

Comment: Are you using @SpringBootTest

Comment: Yes using @SpringbootTest

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using @SpringBootTest annotation.

When you test a Controller you may want narrow the tests to only the web layer by using @WebMvcTest. Any other dependencies required by the controller will be then mocked using @MockBean.

When @WebMvcTest is used Spring Boot instantiates only the web layer rather than the whole context. In an application with multiple controllers, you can even ask for only one to be instantiated for example.

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers =Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest{
@MockBean
private Service service;
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

// test cases
}
```

I noticed that you have the @Transactional annotation in your example. This can indicate that you maybe giving too match responsibilities to your controller and may consider passing Database access related logic to a service/repostory/DAO
See https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Comment: When I use '@Mock Service service;' instead of '@MockBean' it works for that scenario but assertion fails for other test cases.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the tests and failures?

Comment: @Autowired
 private MockMvc mockMvc; as well

Comment: Yes '@Autowired MockMvc'...actually main issue is unsatisfied dependency as '@MockBean Service' mocks Service object in application context  but I need actual object in application context so that '@Bean getCronValue' method can use it and fetch value from db but it fails to get @Autowired Service object.   ....is there any option to '@Mockbean and '@Autowired same Service in controllerTest class or any other technique to resolve it.

Comment: What about mocking the needed value Mockito.wheh(service.getWhatever()).then(...)

Comment: I suggest that you share more code and exception. maybe we can help